# Do open maps move isolated points to isolated points, in general?

Tags: general-topology

Say I have an open map $f : X \rightarrow Y$, and some subset A of X, with an isolated point $a_0$. Would $f(a_0)$ be an isolated point of $f(A)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point $a_0 \in A$ is an isolated point if there is an open subset $O$ of $A$ such that $\{a_0\} = A \cap O$. If $f$ is open we do know that $f[O]$ is open in $Y$. But in general, $f[A \cap O] \subset f[A] \cap f[O]$, with equality only guaranteed when $f$ is 1-1. This suggests looking at non-injective maps:

$f(x) = x^2$ from the reals to the positive reals is an open (and continuous) map. Can you find an $A$ and $a_0$ to be a counterexample?

Comment: Thanks. I had the same thought process but a counterexample didn't immediately come to mind.

Comment: Oops, arrived too late. You were already done when I stopped typing! Nice and succinct explanation.

Comment: Do you mean that $O$ is an open subset of $X$ instead of $A$? Because otherwise wouldn't we have $A\cap O=O$?

Comment: @ThomasE. Yes, $O$ is open in $X$ and $O \cap A$ is open in $A$, by definition. And an isolated point of $A$ is a singleton that is open in $A$ (not necessarily in $X$ as well).

Answer (score 1):

This works if $f$ is injective. Set $A' = A \backslash \{a_0\}$. If $a_0 \in X$ is an isolated point of some $A \subseteq X$, then we can find some open neighbourhood $U$, such that $a_0 \in U$ and $U \cap A' = \emptyset$. Then, $f(U) \cap f(A') = \emptyset$ (because $f$ is injective), so in particular $f(a_0)$ has an open neighbourhood $f(U)$ which is disjoint from $f(A') = f(A) \backslash f(a_0)$ (here, $f(U)$ is open by virtue of $f$ being an open map).

If $f$ is not injective, this may not hold. For example, projection maps are always open, so take $\pi_1 : \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, given by $\pi_1(x_1, x_2) = x_1$. Take $A' \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ as the open square at corners $(-1, 1), (-1, -1), (1, -1)$ and $(1, 1)$, and let $a_0 = (0, 7)$ (say). Clearly, $a_0$ is an isolated point of $A := A' \cup \{a_0\}$, but the image of $A$ under $f$ is the open interval $(-1,1)$, and $f(a_0) = 0$, not an isolated point of that interval.

Comment: Yes, projections also work and might even be easier. Nice one.